# Was the concept of Bishōnen influenced by Hinduism?

Tags: anime-history

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bish%C5%8Dnen), it states that the origin of Bishōnen is linked to Hindu concepts.

> [...] it has roots in ancient Japanese literature, the homosocial and homoerotic ideals of the medieval Chinese imperial court and intellectuals, and **Indian aesthetic concepts carried over from Hinduism**, imported with Buddhism to China.<sup>[3]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[3]</sup> Buckley (2002). *Encyclopedia of Contemporary Japanese Culture. Taylor & Francis.* pp. 188, 522, 553.
>
> <sub>(Emphasis added)</sub>

I checked the book they referenced and quoted, but on the pages, there's no mention of Bishōnen. It's on another page, but it doesn't mention any Hindu concepts, only Chinese Buddhism ones.

Is the statement mentioned correct?

Comment: Welcome to A&M! Could you perhaps include a link to your source, and maybe quote the part you are talking about specifically? You can directly [edit] the information into your question

Comment: Since most of us don't have the book, could you [edit] and add the quotation from the referenced pages?

Comment: That said, based on tracing the revision, the statement was added [on 23 March 2006 by the user Therubaiyat](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=45130174&oldid=45124205&title=Bish%C5%8Dnen). Checking [their contributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Therubaiyat), looks like the user's reasoning is due to [having Bishonen as their thesis topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bish%C5%8Dnen#Edits_needed), but no sources/references provided...